# why use "nginx -g daemonf off" in dockerfiles for nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, daemon

i am containerizing a react app, and i realize alot of people using the line "nginx -g daemon off", please what does that mean
is it good for production?

I also ran the container without the line , and it was working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `nginx -g daemon off` is typically used in Dockerfiles to start the Nginx server as the main process and keep it running in the foreground, instead of running it as a background daemon process. This is because Docker containers are designed to run a single process, and if the main process stops, the container will be stopped as well. By running Nginx in the foreground, the container will keep running as long as Nginx is running.

In terms of using this command in production, it's generally considered a good practice as it ensures that the container is running as expected and allows for easier debugging if issues arise.